# How to handle Unicode in Windows and Linux using c++?

Tags: c++, unicode, c++17, wstring

`std::wstring` is basically the `std::basic_string` template instantiated to `wchar_t`. `wchar_t` is 2 bytes in size on Windows, and 4 bytes on Linux.

Few suggestions were given to me that I should avoid using `std::wstring` altogether if I want to write C++ code which functions the same on Windows and Linux.

Obviously, I can't just use `std::string` on Windows to handle Unicode, and I am advised not to use `std::wstring`. So, what should be done so that the same code works for Linux and Windows?

It's been mentioned that Linux automatically has Unicode support. What does this mean? Is there a simple code example which explains how the same code handles Unicode in Windows and Linux?

What is the importance of locale here, and why do I need to use locale?

Comment: When you say "unicode handling", what do you mean by that? Are you talking about reading/writing files that are encoded in some UTF format? Are you talking about reading/writing data to stdin/stdout that is encoded in UTF? Surprisingly, these aren't the same thing, as stdin/out belongs to the OS, so it really depends on how the console works as to whether it is even viable. When it comes to Unicode in C++, you really need to spell out the specific tasks you want to do.

Comment: @NicolBolas - Lets say my use case is to read/write files encoded in Unicode. Can we answer my questions in that context? My intention is to know what will this involve.

I was under the impression that when we say application supports unicode then it should handle stdin/stdout and files read/write both?

Comment: @Test there is more to "application supports Unicode" than just console & file I/O. There is UI display of strings, transmission of strings, memory storage of strings, parsing strings, etc. A lot goes into string handling. In any case, you *can* use `std::string` for Unicode, if you limit it to UTF-8. And you *can* use `std::wstring` for cross-platform Unicode, if you don't make assumptions about its character size. If you really want exact behavior across platforms, then consider `std::u16string` and `std::u32string`, though using a dedicated Unicode library, like libiconv or ICU, is best.

Comment: @Test: It is helpful to read [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8). It has an example also.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - You said i can use std::string for Unicode but then you mentioned  If I really want exact behavior across platforms, then consider std::u16string and std::u32string. What this means? Can you detail a bit?

Comment: @Test by design, `std::u16string` is meant to be a UTF-16 string on all platforms, and `std::u32string` is meant to be a UTF-32 string on all platforms. You have to go out of your way to break that. Whereas `std::string` *can* be used for a UTF-8 string, but you have to go out of your way to enforce it.

Comment: _"...Lets say my use case is to read/write files encoded in Unicode...."_ then you need to decide on the Unicode encoding for these files.  Will the encoding be same on each platform or will you use the native platform encoding? Will you be writing a Byte-Order-Mark (BOM) to the files?

Comment: `Obviously, I can't just use std::string on Windows to handle Unicode` who said that? Obviously if the locale is UTF-8 then `std::string` can store any Unicode strings

Comment: @RemyLebeau why don't just use `std::u8string`?

Comment: @phuclv being able to store UTF-8 in `std::string` has nothing to do with locales. And `std::u8string` doesn't exist until C++20. At least `std::u16string`/`std::u32string` exist in C++11, and `std::wstring` even earlier.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes locales play a very important role, otherwise `std::string s{"somé Ünicode string ⚡️"}` may not work as expected because the compiler can use another encoding

Comment: On the other hand, `std::string s{"som\xC3\xA9 \xC3\x9Cnicode string \xE2\x9A\xA1\xEF\xB8\x8F\xF0\x9F\x97\xA3"}` does not rely on the compiler's locale. Nor should `std::string s{u8"somé Ünicode string ⚡️"}` You don't NEED a locale to store UTF-8 in a `std::string`